# Renaming values inside json files with Python script

Tags: python, rename

Need to rename value inside json files.
example:
`[somefilename123.json]`

`{"Real/Fake": "Fake", "Fake source": "Print", "Fake Type": "PrintFolded"}`

Need to rename value `"Print"` to `"PrintCut"`

Comment: check [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json

with open("some_file.json",'r') as f:
    dict_obj = json.loads(f.read())

dict_obj["Fake source"] = "PrintCut"

with open("some_file.json", "w+") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(dict_obj, indent = 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
import json

with open("replayScript.json", "r+") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    data["Fake source"] = "PrintCut"
    f.seek(0)  # rewind
    json.dump(data, f)
    f.truncate()
```

Answer (score 0):

json is basically a string format; if all you need to do is replace "Print" with "PrintCut" you can simply

1. Open the file in 'r' mode
2. read contents of the json file
3. do a simple [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) for the given string
4. close the file
5. Open the file in 'w' mode
6. write file to disk

Comment: Do NOT do this. This will replace *all* occurrences of `Print` in the file. What if the content of some key contains `Print`?

Comment: @AbhyudayaSharma True; my main point was that json is a simple text/string format; at times simple solutions may be sufficient rather than full blown json processing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach. Manipulate the json as Python dictionary, delete the previous entry and insert the key with new value.

```py
import json
with open('somefilename123.json') as json_file:
    json_dict = json.load(json_file)
    key = 'Fake source'
    del json_dict[key]
    json_dict[key] = 'PrintCut'

with open('somefilename123.json', 'w') as output_file:
    json.dump(json_dict, output_file)
```

Output file contents

> {"Real/Fake": "Fake", "Fake Type": "PrintFolded", "Fake source": "PrintCut"}

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with json.load and json.dump, like:

```
import json


def reset_value(path_to_json, key, value):
    with open(path_to_json) as f:
        d = json.load(f)
        d[key] = value
    with open(path_to_json, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(d, f)

json_file = "./somefilename123.json"
reset_value(json_file, "Fake source", "PrintCut")
```